# Audio gets removed while converting mp4 to intermediate state for concatenation using ffmpeg

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg

When I use the following command -

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts`

the audio from the given input mp4 file gets automatically removed.
I am running this from a python sub-process.
I want to retain the audio from the original file.

The mp4 is an output of the following mencoder command

`mencoder -ss start-time -endpos end-time -oac pcm -ovc copy original.mp4 -o input.mp4`

The log is as follows :

`

```
Input #0, avi, from '/home/pranav/Desktop/video/video_module_05-06-2017/temp/072147_1mp4test1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : MEncoder 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1
  Duration: 00:00:03.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1440 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(tv), 640x268 [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:67], 32 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, mpegts, to '/home/pranav/Desktop/video/video_module_05-06-2017/temp/072147_1mp4intermediate1.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 640x268 [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:67], q=2-31, 32 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 24 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   73 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     599kB time=00:00:03.04 bitrate=1612.5kbits/s    
video:12kB audio:517kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 13.229376%
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
```

`

Comment: Please have a look at [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Did you try different mp4 files or just that one..as the snippet is right, probably your mp4 is not good.

Comment: Share the full log from your command.